# Django: No module named apps

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, virtualenv, django-apps

The module `django.apps` cannot be found. It is a module normally included in Django, therefore I don't understand where this error comes from.

This happens after installing djangorestframework and adding this line:

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
```

The CLI output shows that Django version 1.6 is detected:

```
In [1]: from django.apps import apps
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-380cc652af3e> in <module>()
----> 1 from django.apps import apps

ImportError: No module named apps

In [2]: import django

In [3]: django.VERSION
Out[3]: (1, 6, 11, 'final', 0)
```

Full exception:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://www.somedomain.com/
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named apps
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/utils/model_meta.py in <module>, line 11
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/workspace/djangoserver',
 '/home/ubuntu/workspace/djangoserver',
 '/home/ubuntu/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
Server time:    Thu, 26 Nov 2015 13:25:42 +0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/), in bold, at the top:

> **New in Django 1.7.**

From your question:

```
Django Version: 1.6.11
```

Comment: You are right, I was checking `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/reusable-apps/`. I still don't know where this module gets called from and how to avoid it in 1.6.11.

Comment: If you look at *Exception Location*, you can see that the exception is being raised by Django REST framework, which [currently requires](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/#requirements) Django 1.7+. Note that Django 1.6.X is end of life and no longer gets security releases, so it would be a good idea to upgrade.

Comment: That changes the question to what framework should I use to make Django work with MongoDB and REST. `mongoengine` requires `Django non-rel`, which has current version 1.6

Comment: I'm afraid that recommending frameworks is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Seems that the last DRF version that supports Django v1.6 is 3.2.5: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/